# How do I create a "stage.update ()" exclusively for the object?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, easeljs, stage

On my screen I have 10 images and 6 texts. I know that every time you call "stage.update()" is redesigned view screen.

I have only two objects that need constant "stage.update ()". The first is a chronometer that needs every second to update a text and the second is an image that can be dragged around the screen.

How do I create a "stage.update ()" exclusively for the object?

---

Attempts:

1. I made an array of "stage" for a single canvas:

   ```
   canvas = document.getElementsByTagName ('canvas') [0];
   stage['full'] = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
   stage['chronometer'] = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
   ```

   The problem that when executed, one cancels the other:

   ```
   stage ['full']. update ();
   stage ['chronometer']. update ();
   ```
2. I tried to create Container.

   ```
   containerTest = new createjs.Container(); 
   stage.addChild(containerTest);
   ```

   Problem?
   Could not update only what is in the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the ticker and a counter, i think you can do your stuff:

```
var counter = 0;
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", handleTick);
var chronometer = ...
chronometer.cache(xChrono,yChrono,widthChrono,heightChrono);

function handleTick(event) {
   // handle your drag and drop
   // ...
   if (counter == maxValue) { // maxValue = 1000 / createjs.Ticker.getInterval()
       // redraw your chronometer
       // ...
       counter = 0;
       chronometer.updateCache();
   } else {
       counter++;
   }
   stage.update();
}
```

Comment: It's more or less what I do. However each change in the chronometer running "stage.update ()" will draw the whole screen again. In another forum pointed to create two "canvas" with a "stage" for each, but do not know which option is more costly to process.

Comment: Maybe "DisplayObject.cache()" is the method that you looking for then. It allows you to prevent the cached content to be re-rendered each tick. With this, you could 'cache' your chronometer object and then update this cache each second.

Comment: Interesting. Could you give an example?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Also I redirect you to the documentation [link](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/DisplayObject.html#method_cache)

Comment: Reading the official website did the opposite of your example. Sorry I'm starting in HTML5 and my english is not good. I understand that I need to cache the objects that will not be changed and let the chronometer out of the cache. Was that it? (I know it's "reverse" in the example).

Comment: My bad, I reversed it all in my head ... But yeah, the point is to cache the object(s) that won't be changed often.